# Redux-from 'file input field' triggers validation triggers before selecting the file

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

Am using Redux 6.0.5.
I have a render field component for 'file' input type and i have an onChange event in that file component which gets the uploaded file name and I display it in later.

I have facing problem in error validation function,
steps to reproduce:

1. Click the upload button the SYNC validation is triggered(Since there is no file at this moment, which set's 'mandatory error msg')
2. Then when uploading the file, onChange event, I get the uploaded file name and save it in my state
3. Mandatory error message is getting displayed since SYNC validate is occured before selecting the file

---

```
const labels = defineMessages({
      mandatoryField: {
        id: 'bo_setting_mandatory_field',
        defaultMessage: `This is Mandatory Field`
    }
});
const validate = values => {
    const errors = {};
    const coverPicture = values.get('coverPicture');
    if (!coverPicture)
        errors.coverPicture = labels.mandatoryField;
     return errors;
}

const RenderFileUploadField = ({ input, placeholder, label, buttonLabel, type, meta: { touched, error }, onChange, accept}) => {
    const isError = touched && error;
    return <div className={isError ? 'form-group has-error' : 'form-group'}>
        <label className="control-label">{label}</label>
        <div className="inputGroup">
            <input className="form-control" {...input} type={type} accept={accept} onChange={onChange} />
            <div className="inputFile">
                <small></small>
                <input readOnly={true} name={`${input.name}Text`} type="text" value={placeholder} className="form-control" />
                <span className={isError ? 'error active text-danger' : 'error'}>
                    {isError ? <FormattedMessage id={error.id} defaultMessage={error.defaultMessage} className={isError ? 'error active' : 'error'} />
                        : null}
                </span>
                <span className="inputAddon"><span>{buttonLabel}</span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

class From extends Component {
    handleSubmit(data) {
        console.log("SUBMITTED")
        console.log(data.toJS())
    }
    handleFile(fieldName, event) {
        const { fields } = this.props;
        const files = [...event.target.files];
        if (files.length > 0) {
            this.props.uploadFile(fieldName, files[0].name)
        }
        else if (files.length === 0) {
            this.props.uploadFile(fieldName, '')
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    render() {
        const {formatMessage} = this.props.intl;
        const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting, error, reset } = this.props;

        return (
                               <form className="equalColumn">
 <Field name="coverPicture" type="file" onChange={this.handleFile.bind(this, 'coverPicture')}
                                        label={formatMessage(labels.defaultCoverPic)}
                                        component={RenderFileUploadField}
                                        buttonLabel={formatMessage(labels.uploadFile)}
                                        placeholder={coverPicture ? coverPicture : formatMessage(labels.defaultCoverPic)}
                                        accept='image/*'
                                        value={null} />
                                        <a href="#" className="btn btn-success" onClick={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))} >{formatMessage(labels.saveTheFrom)}</a>
                    </form>


        );
    }

}

From.propTypes = {
    intl: intlShape.isRequired
};


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        }
}

const injectIntlDecorator = _.curryRight(injectIntl)
export default compose(injectIntlDecorator(),
    reduxForm({
        form: 'settings',
        destroyOnUnmount: false, 
        validate
    }),
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        actions,
        null,
        { pure: false }
    )
)(From);
```

---

In short: It seems like, onClick of Upload button 'OnBlur [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9ZbW.png)' validation is trigger before selecting file and validation is not triggered after the file is changed...
can anyone help me on this?